# I am having an issue with my order by in codeigniter

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

For some reason when I do order by Date_Scheduled desc it is still leaving the oldest date first. I am trying to get it so that the newest date shows first and oldest date last. Not sure is I am writing this correctly.

Here is my model it is the get employee function.

```
<?php

class Employee_model extends CI_Model 
{

    public function insert_employee($data)
    {
    $this->db->insert('employee_list',$data); 
return $this->db->insert_id(); 
    }
    public function get_employee()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('employee_list');
        $this->db->where('status',1);
        $this->db->order_by ("Date_Scheduled", "desc"); 
        $this->db->order_by("Scheduled_Area", "desc");
        $this->db->order_by("Time_Reported", "desc");  




        $query =$this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
    public function delete_employee($id,$data)
    {
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $this->db->update('employee_list',$data);
            return print_r($data);


    }
    public function edit_employee($id)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('employee_list');
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $this->db->where('status',1);
        $query =$this->db->get();
        return $query->result();

    }
    public function update_employee($data,$id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $this->db->update('employee_list',$data);
        return print_r($data);

    }
}
```

Comment: It's a stretch, but what is the data type of date_scheduled?

Comment: It is navchar (50) would that be the issue I have the date echoing in the field

Comment: I need it so the users are able to change the date

Comment: If I let the system enter the date it will not allow the change

Comment: What do you mean by the system does not allow the change?

Comment: I need it so the user sees the date and allow them to change the date. Thats why I made it as nvachar 50.

Comment: I am incorrect does allow user to change but still does not reverse to and put newest date first.

Answer (score 0):

This answer solves part of your problem, because you should handle dates with the correct column type `date` and not `varchar`.

If the result of your query always returns `ORDER BY ASC`, you can flip the array.

```
array_reverse($this->Employee_model->get_employee());
```

Comment: where would i put that in my model or controller?

Comment: this is in my conrtoller now     $data['employee']=$this->employee_model->get_employee();

Comment: I tried didn't work I guess I will change my nvarchar 50 to date

Comment: changing it to date didn't work either still oldest date first

Comment: You shouldn't use the code I told you in your model. You should use it on your controller. `$data['employee'] = array_reverse($this->Employee_model->get_employee());`

Comment: I tried it in the controller it did not reverse. the List stayed the same.

Comment: http://www.roytuts.com/sort-table-data-in-ascending-or-descending-order-in-codeigniter/ I am going to try this tutorial and see how I can implement it with my program