# Not Sure How to call Store Procedure in Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I am having an issue calling a stored procedure in my model not sure if I am doing it right the screen is coming up blank, also do i need to auto load anything to call a stored procedure?

```
<?php

class Employee_model extends CI_Model 
{

    public function insert_employee($data)
    {
    $this->db->insert('employee_list',$data); 
return $this->db->insert_id(); 
    }
    public function get_employee()
    {

        $this->db->query("call {storedprocedure Select_employeelist} ");

        $query =$this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
    public function delete_employee($id,$data)
    {
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $this->db->update('employee_list',$data);
            return print_r($data);


    }
    public function edit_employee($id)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('employee_list');
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $this->db->where('status',1);
        $query =$this->db->get();
        return $query->result();

    }
    public function update_employee($data,$id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $this->db->update('employee_list',$data);
        return print_r($data);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call a procedure from codeigniter

Consider `test_proc` as your procedure. Then it should be

```
$this->db->query("call test_proc()");
```

If you need to to send parameters then

```
$query = $this->db->query($test_proc,array('id'=>'1','name'=>'test','address'=>'abc'));
```

To see the result then

```
print_r($query);
```

Comment: This is the one but I am not sure clear enough re passing in variables. The `$test_proc` variable should look like a normal query string like `call test_proc(?,?,?);`

Comment: I can't even find any official support in CI's official link http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/search.html?q=procedure&check_keywords=yes&area=default#

Comment: How would I make it so the columns will show up like Date_Scheduled, Reason, Employee_Name.

Comment: Won't be the only thing not covered. I will up vote after a bit of pedantic testing - currently on mobile

Comment: @Veronica You want to display the fetched result from procedure ?

Comment: I created the store procedure because I am having issue with order by in my code every time I do an order_by Date_Scheduled desc the date still stays the same shows 2014 2015 2016 when I need it to go the other way 2016 2015 2014 so I figured if I did it directly in the sql might work

Comment: I also tried an array reverse and still didn't work here is the link to my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28701284/i-am-having-an-issue-with-my-order-by-in-codeigniter/28702146?noredirect=1#comment45718039_28702146

Comment: Then you should print_r($query) i have updated my answer

Comment: Is there appropriate data and the values you sent exist.. Can you try directly in the phpmyadmin ??

Comment: I am using MSSQL not MYSQL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71719/discussion-between-veronica-and-sulthan-allaudeen).

Comment: A stored procedure is not useful to you in this situation, if you are only using the procedure one, it still acts like one query, its only when you use it multiple times it gets cached. please update your question to include your goals/problems to get a better alternative.

Comment: Hello there, I m facing this problem at the moment, I can't make my code to run. any help would be appreciated. here is my code: **$this->db->query("exec pr_swat_report_new param1, param2, param3, param4");** I also tried  **$this->db->query("pr_swat_report_new param1, param2, param3, param4");** but still no luck at all